# asp .net mvc website login/register works on local but not on server .net 4.5.2 vs2105

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I created an mvc website.
Framework: .net 4.5.2 
visual studio 2105 community edition.

When I run project On my local machine, it works perfectly.
I try to use register and login pages, they are working perfectly as well. I can create new users and then login with them.

But when I copy project on server (Windows server 2012), project works perfectly but not register/login pages.

It gives error:

> An error occurred while processing your request.

I copied App_Data folder as well. There is a `.mdf` file in it.

This is the connection string in web.config

```
add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mvc1-20151111034033.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mvc1-20151111034033;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: You will need to host your database SQL-Server you cant use LocalDB  on the server, you cannot access the DB on the server like that, you will then need to mod you connection string

Comment: LocalDb exists only within the context of Visual Studio. As soon as your code is running outside of Visual Studio, you need a real database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update the connection string

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Server_Name;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;Integrated Security=True;User ID=Username;Password=Password;" />
```